# Bind a TextBox to a Datagrid and a Database in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid, textbox

I have a `TextBox` that takes data from a single cell in a `DataGrid` and I want to send the content to a database. This is how I bind the `TextBox` to my `DataGrid` and works fine:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TestText" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyDGTest, Path=SelectedItem.Test}" />
```

Now I want the content to save to a database:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TestText" Text="{Binding TestTable.Test, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

My problem is that i can use only 1 binding at the same time.

EDIT:

If its not possible to bind to 2 sources is there any way to access this `TextBox` from my `ViewModel`? I can than save the value directly to the database.

Thx for any help.

Comment: Can't you just give MyDGTest's `SelectedItem` a two-way binding to your view-model?

Comment: But how to send the content of the SelectedItem to the Database?

Comment: Do it from the view model, in that property's setter?  (Alternatively, you could set up a command that executes when the selection changes.)

Comment: If i access a component from my ViewModel i always get null, even though my TextBox/DataGrid is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution. I use proxy for in and out binding as explained in  http://www.11011.net/wpf-binding-properties . The only difference is that i use new Action and not new Operation (i couldn't find any class with this name).